# android starting Activity from Intent in onClickListener in common class returns error

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I have a navigation button that I use in each class and want to set its onClickListener in the class that contains all the common code. However I get a

```
"The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}"
```

error in startActivity(i).

The relevant code is:

```
    public static void initiateNavigationButton(Context context, View view, int layoutResource) {
    final Context classContext = context;

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(classContext);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, (ViewGroup) view);

    Button navigationButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.navigation_button);

    navigationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            Intent i = new Intent(classContext, HomeActivity.class);

            startActivity(i); 
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inside an inner class that implements the `View.OnClickListener`.

That class does not have a `startActivity` method that you could call, so you need to wrap it in order to access the parent activity's method. Assuming that your class' name is 'MyActivity', change the line `startActivity(i);` to

```
MyActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```